# Gradle: Could not create SecurityManager

Tags: java, linux, gradle, teamcity

I am currently trying to get some tests run in gradle for a shared build server. I get the following error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM    
java.lang.InternalError: Could not create SecurityManager:  
worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.BootstrapSecurityManager
    at sun.misc.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:102)
    at sun.misc.Launcher.<clinit>(Launcher.java:53)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.initSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1451)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1436)
```

The JVM commandline arguments from running with --debug are:

```
-DisTestMode=true
-Djava.security.manager=worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.BootstrapSecurityManager                 
-DtestLocators
-javaagent:../expandedArchives/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.8.jar_cbks496gfbgpke4b5ek12xen8/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=../../jacoco/testSpringContext_cnt_dmabtec.exec,append=true,inclnolocationclasses=false,dumponexit=true,output=file,jmx=false
-Xms128m
-Dfile.encoding=US-ASCII
-Duser.country=US
-Duser.language=en
-Duser.variant
```

I've tried running with different versions of gradle on local and on server to compare:
2.14.1 on local vs 2.14.1 on server
4.10.1 on local vs 4.5.x on server

- On local, it will always pass all tests regardless of gradle version.
- On server, it will always fail when it tries to one one specific    test.
- Both local and server have the same JVM arguments.
- Both are using java JDK 8.
- Same result if .gradle directory in working directory is deleted prior to gradle task
- Cannot delete the /.gradle directory with gradle-worker.jar since it is a shared build server (I don't the permissions)

Does anyone have any ideas as to what is the issue? If you need more information, please ask and I will provide if I am able to. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 export GRAILS_OPTS='-Xmx4g'
```

worked for me as charm

Comment: Be very careful not to put a leading space or 2 spaces anywhere in GRAILS_OPTS. It will cause this error.

Answer (score 32):

This occurs when ~/.gradle/daemon folder is corrupted in MacOS/Unix.
Forcefully removing the daemon folder resolved the issue for me.

```
rm -rf ~/.gradle/daemon
```

Answer (score 4):

Hi I could resolve my Problem with deleting the cache folder in the users home and then remove the .gradle folder in the projects folder. After that, I used gradle init and gradle wrapper to initialize it. 
Important I had to restart my computer (Windows) because some files in the cache folder were locked. Be sure, that everything is deleted inside the cache folder. I had some hanging gradle daemons without deleting everything.

Answer (score 1):

```
rm -rf ~/.gradle/daemon
```

Must solve the problem as it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

For windows if you are unable to delete the cache follow below steps;
go to C:\Users{You}.gradle\daemon{gradle_version}

1. Delete all log files
2. Select *.bin and *.lock file and quickly back to {gradle_version} folder and delete that folder.

Comment: This doesn't provide an answer to the question. The question is not about windows.